# Grafana bar width too small

Tags: grafana, flux

i would like to know how i could get a bigger bar width in my histogram like bar graph.

This is the graph how it looks rigth now:
[image: the graph]

And this is the corresponding query in flux:
[image: the query]

Answer (score 1):

Encountered the same issue with Grafana 7.3.7 and InfluxDB 1.8.3.

It looks like Grafana bar width is sensitive to the last date interval in the time series (use a Table visualization to verify this).

A workaround is to use `_start` times instead of `_stop` times of the windows. One can do this by performing the transformations manually that `agregateWindow()` would otherwise use (these transformations are described in the [docs](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.0/query-data/flux/window-aggregate/#unwindow-aggregate-tables)).

You would then have:

```
from(bucket: "piMeter")
  |> range(start: -1d)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => (
    r._measurement == "downsampled_energy" and
    r._field == "sum_Gesamt")
  )
  |> fill(value: 0.0)
  |> window(every: 1h)
  |> sum()
  |> duplicate(column: "_start", as: "_time")
  |> window(every: inf)
```

Answer (score 0):

Along the lines of what @cidermole said, I was able to achieve consistent and reasonable width bars by extending the width of my most recent window to a full window.  Try adding a stop argument to your range like:

```
range(start: -1d, stop: date.truncate(t: experimental.addDuration(d: 1h, to: v.timeRangeStop), unit: 1h))
```

You'll need to import some libraries at the start of your script:

```
import "experimental"
import "date"
```

I was using Influx 2.1.1 and Grafana 8.2.4.  See [this post](https://community.grafana.com/t/bar-graph-problem-bars-in-dashboard-are-ok-then-suddenly-they-become-really-thin/45197).