# Set width of bars in Grafana when using flux query

Tags: bar-chart, grafana, influxdb, flux

I have the following flux query that aggregates on a monthly basis

```
from(bucket: "some-bucket")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == "some-value" and r._field == "some-other-value")
  |> aggregateWindow(every: 1mo, fn: sum)
```

that gives the following bar chart

[image]

As you can see the bars are very thin. I would like them to be one month wide. Is there a way to manually set this or a different way to construct the query to get Grafana to detect this?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this has to do with the time spacing of the very last record. A workaround for me was to use the `_start` column of groups (instead of the default `_stop`) to restore the `_time` column.

Try this:

```
from(bucket: "some-bucket")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == "some-value" and r._field == "some-other-value")
  |> aggregateWindow(every: 1mo, fn: sum, timeSrc: "_start")
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/66107599/1616948 for details.